# Is the Nazi party legal in the German parliament?

Tags: nazism

I have asked one question in lawer se site, which closed so I asked that question here. The question is show below ([link of main question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86885/is-the-nazi-party-legal-in-the-german-parliament?noredirect=1#comment194491_86885))

Does the Nazism party exist and is legal in the German parliament?

I have asked one question in law we site, which closed so I moved the question here, the question is show at below:

We assume that This party is the same as the Hitler party but without the sign of the Nazi swastika flag,and exist in German parlemant.

**Update 1:**

The main question is closed and I can not have more answer or comment on it, so I can delete that question at that se site or have both of them.

One of the answer of the lawyers se site was as shown below:

> > Does the Nazism party exist and is legal in the German parliament?
>
> ## No.
>
> The Nazi party was found to be a criminal organisation and abolished
> in the Nuremberg Trials of 1946.
>
> Trying to refound/reform a criminal organisation is illegal in itself.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Party#Defeat_and_abolition
>
> https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalsozialistische_Deutsche_Arbeiterpartei#Parteiverbot_1945

Comment: Although the question was closed, you already have a couple of answers, which are quite clear.  "No" the Nazi party was declared a criminal organisation and banned. There is no nazi party in the German parliament.  Are those answers unclear?  What more do you expect from this forum?

Comment: I know this is the answer, but that se site, has closed the question and it would be deleted or unasseable at future, so I want to the question be opened to show this question to my friends, and give them the opportunity to write some comments and give their answer which is showing nazi party are legal and exist in German parlemant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is utterly trivial.

Comment: @jojbgzkkjx_rocketestate724_com "I want to the question be opened to show this question to my friends, and give them the opportunity to write some comments and give their answer which is showing nazi party are legal and exist in German parlemant." I refer you to [this meta post](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-a-push-question).

Comment: @Arno I think there is an interesting question in there, when you consider parties like the NPD or Dritter Weg, which are still legal in Germany (in the case of the NPD despite the government trying to outlaw them). They aren't in the Bundestag but the NPD has been in state legislatures and the European parliament. They also aren't "the same as the Hitler party" but rather follow in certain traditions laid out by them.

Answer (score 6):

No ["THE" Nazi Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Party) was banned and is not allowed to exist any more and using its symbols, slogans etc, is a punishable offence (penal code [§86](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p0922), [§86a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p0933) and [§130](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1368)) .

That being said there are unfortunately still contenders for "A" Nazi party. That is a political party whose philosophy and/or members align closely with the Nazi ideology. Here it's a bit more tricky because due to it's history the German constitution isn't too happy about banning political parties. It's possible and there is precedent of it with 2 examples the SRP (direct successor of the Nazi party) and the KPD (Communist party of Germany). Though they were both banned in the early to mid 50s when the SRP apparently openly proclaimed to be a successor of the Nazi party and had a paramilitary wing and the KPD well was the communist party during the cold war.
Though that's a long time ago and unless they cross the line between legal and illegal, even an opposition to the constitution is at least to some regard covered by freedom on speech, so long as it only applies constitutional means.

So for example the [NPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Democratic_Party_of_Germany) (national-"democratic" party of Germany and successor of the successor of the Nazi Party) is one where it's basically common knowledge that they are a Nazi Party. The "national-democratic" is similar to the "national-socialist" of the Nazi party, not necessarily to be understood as two words with commonly agreed upon definitions, but as 1 word where the latter parts meaning can vary drastically from any commonly used definitions. It also seems like piling up convictions for violating the previously mentioned paragraphs as well as holocaust denial and assaults on political enemies and so on are somewhat of a "rite of passage". Google yields that in 2013 about 1/4-1/3 of it's members had prior convictions. So they basically walk on razor's edge in terms of being a criminal organization or just an organization with a suspiciously high amount of criminals. Even if they publicly avoid the label of a Nazi party, virtually no one in their right mind would vote for them "by accident", not knowing what they stand for. There also have been several attempts at banning this party though so far they have failed. The last ruled that the party is anti-constitutional but also irrelevant so that a ban isn't necessary. They are not members of the federal parliament (5% of the votes are required to have seats), but they are occasionally in the local parliaments of some states.

Another contester would be the [AfD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_for_Germany). Which has a slightly different origin story. They are a fairly new party, founded in 2013, when the 2nd attempt at banning the NPD started, though at first probably a coincidence. Programmatically they started out as an anti-€ party of some economically right wing people, then took on some anti-EU sentiments in general, which apparently attracted lots of far right nationalists and since then, those extremists regularly replaced the leadership with ever further right wing (fascist) people. The right wing of this far right wing party (only called "[der Flügel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Fl%C3%BCgel)"="the wing" - no joke) was till it officially dissolved (yet still unofficially active), founded and lead by Björn Höcke. Someone who lost a court case of being called a fascist, because there was too much truth to the case to be an insult. And even former leaders admit that the AfD is not rooted in the ["liberal democratic basic order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_democratic_basic_order) (that's official term for the minimal consensus of democratic parties). So they used to be less overtly Nazi-aligned than the NPD and tried to appeal to a wider conservative spectrum as well as employ xenophobic populism, but they steadily move further to the fascist domain and are now solidly grounded there with even internal attempts at presenting a "center right" image failing regularly. However unfortunately they are members of parliament as they managed to score 10.3% in the last election. Which meant a drop of 2.3% from the results from the election before. Though in some states they managed to score close to 30% of the votes.

Now while it's technically possible for a party to be (neo-)fascist without referencing the Nazis, these particular far right parties have not managed to get rid of occasionally evoking sympathy, praise or downplaying of the Nazi era. Apparently far right nationals need to have a "glorious past" to be proud of, which in Germany only really works if one "recontextualizes" the Nazi era as either something good or at least "not as bad" and far in the past.

PS: There are some other microparties that get founded or dissolved but these 2 are the currently most relevant ones.

TL;DR: No. The Nazi party is banned as well as all official successor and subsidiary parties. There are parties who walk the line of legality and test the boundaries of that ban, but in public discourse they would refrain from using the label.